# Replacing placeholder on page load

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies

I am using Divi theme on WordPress.
I am trying to replace a placeholder with a cookie value but no matter what I try to do it does not stick.

I have used

```
document.onload = document.getElementyById('budget_field').placeholder = getCookie("recommendedAmount");
```

As well as with `document.ready`. It only does work when I hard code a value.
I also created a button to `alert()` with the cookie value and it is there.

Is there an easier way to replace the placeholder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById('input').placeholder = 'bar';
})
```

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="foo" />
```